# Copy Site Collection in same Web Application

Tags: site-collection, site

How can I copy a Site Collection to the same Web Application?

I have got Public Site, so I can't save this as a template, or can I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to copy to site in same site collection you need to add a new content Database in that web application, otheirwise it will throw the error. here are the steps:

- [Create a new Content Database](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc825317(v=office.14).aspx) in the web application
- Take the Backup of the Site sites collection using [Backup-spsite.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901(v=office.15).aspx)
- Now [restore](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788(v=office.15).aspx) the site collection and using the database paramter to point newly created DB.`Restore-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak -Force -DatabaseServer SQLBE1 -DatabaseName SQLDB1`